# Adding react-icons to a card

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for an example of where a react icon is used in a card. See my code below. I have tried entering it as a prop, but no image is shown. Below I am adding it inside of `<Cards>` I am using this icon . What is the correct approach to add the icon below? thank you in advance, I'm new to this.

Card UI file:

```
import "../card-style.css";

const Cards = props =>{
    
    return (
        <div className="card text-center">
        <div className="overflow">
          <img
            src={props.imgsrc}
            alt={props.alt}
            className="card-img-top"
            icon={props.icon}
            />
          <a className="card-link">
            <span className="card-icon">
              
            <div className="card-body text-dark">
            <h4 className="card-title">{props.title}</h4>
          </div>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
)
    
} 

export default Cards;
```

CardsDeck component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../card-style.css";
import Cards from "./CardsUI";
import logo from "../img/logo.png";
import create from "../img/create.png"
import { BsFillBagPlusFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import executive from "../img/executive.png"
import operational from "../img/operations.jpg"

export default function CardsDeck() {
    const link1 = "Create Request";
    const link2 = "Executive Dashboard";
    const link3 = "Operational Dashboard";
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <Cards title={link1} imgsrc={create}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <Cards title={link2}>
              <BsFillBagPlusFill />
            </Cards>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <Cards imgsrc={operational} title={link3} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello in order to add photos/icons you have to create an assets folder inside of your root folder of your project, then you can add images folder there and take the relative path and import it in the image url.

import the image

```
import Yourimage from '../images/image.png';

var imgStyle= {
  Image: `url(${Yourimage})`
};

class ImgComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div style={imgStyle}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try maybe to create image component and use it on your card component.Ask again if there are more problems,hope this will help you.